# IJCADでのDWFファイルの作成方法

Tags: .net, ijcad

.net APIを利用して自動でIJCADからアクティブ図面をDWFファイルに出力しようとしています。
SendCommandでEXPORTを呼出してDWFファイルを作成しているのですが、横長の図面でも縦長に出力されます。PAGESETUPなどで設定を変更しても反映されないようです。
EXPORTDWFの置き換えることも考えましたが、ファイル選択画面が表示されます。
図面通りにDWFファイルを作成する方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

自分はIJCAD2019を使っています。Exportだと確かにPageSetupの変更が反映されてないですが、ExportDWFだと反映されますよ。図面通りにDWFファイルを作成したいならExportDWFの方が良いと思います。
もしその.NET APIで書いたコードを見せてもらえたら、さらにアドバイスが出来るかもしれません。